# React-query infiniteQuery - how to fix additional pageParam type checking

Tags: react-query, code-cleanup, react-tsx, tanstackreact-query

i have bumped into following issue, i'm trying to implement infiniteQuery by using react-query tanstack, but i can't do it without additional checking of pageParam on it's type of number.

Could you please tell me how can i simplify this code without affecting of files structure

**ApiClient.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";

const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'
})

class API<T> {
    constructor(public endpoint: string) {
    }

    getAll = (pageParam: number) => {
       return apiClient.get<T[]>(this.endpoint, {
            params: {
                _page: pageParam
            }
        }).then(res => res.data)
            .catch(err => err)
    }
}

export default API
```

**todo-service.ts**

```
import API from "../api-service/api-client.ts";

export interface Todo {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    completed: boolean;
}
const UseTodoService = new API<Todo>('todos')

export default UseTodoService;
```

**useTodo hook**

```
import {useInfiniteQuery} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import {CACHE_KEY_TODO} from "../constants.ts";
import UseTodoService, {Todo} from "../http-service/todo-service.ts";

const UseTodo = () => {
   return useInfiniteQuery<Todo[], Error>({
       queryKey: CACHE_KEY_TODO,
       queryFn: ({pageParam}) => {
           if (typeof pageParam === 'number') return UseTodoService.getAll(pageParam);
           else throw new Error("pageParam must be a number.");
       },
       getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allPages) =>
           lastPage.length > 0 ? allPages.length + 1 : undefined,
       initialPageParam: 1
   })
    }


export default UseTodo;
```

**Todo component**

```
import useTodo from "../hooks/useTodo.ts";

function TodoList() {
    const {data, fetchNextPage } = useTodo()
    return <>
        <h1>TodoList</h1>
        <ul className="list-group">
            {data?.pages.map(todos => todos.map((todo, index) =>
                <li className="list-group-item" key={index}>{todo.title}</li>))}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={() => fetchNextPage()} className="btn btn-primary mt-2">Fetch More</button>
    </>
}

export default TodoList;
```

i'm expecting help of how you can refactor this code to make it more cleaner and without additional checking type of pageParams

```
 queryFn: ({pageParam}) => {
           if (typeof pageParam === 'number') return UseTodoService.getAll(pageParam);
           else throw new Error("pageParam must be a number.");
       },
```

Answer (score 1):

`pageParam` is **already typed** as `number`. You can remove additional type checking.

When you define a variable in TypeScript with a specific type, such as `initialPageParam: 1`, TypeScript infers the type of that variable based on the assigned value. In this case, `initialPageParam` is inferred to be of type `number` because you've assigned it the value 1.

The `pageParam` variable is also of type `TPageParam`, which we can infer is a type alias for number based on your usage. Therefore, you don't need to perform a typeof check on `pageParam` because TypeScript already knows it's a `number`

- https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/guides/query-functions#queryfunctioncontext
- https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/reference/useInfiniteQuery